# prime factors of $ n^{2}+4$ is congruent to 1 or 5 (mod 8)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

prove that the prime factors  of **$n^{2}+4$** , $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ are congruent to $ 1 \ or \ 5 \ (mod \ 8)$. $$$$ I can that the statement holds for n=1,2,3 , so can i use induction principle ? If there is any other way to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Have you heard about quadratic residues?

Comment: _Odd_ prime factors, maybe?

Comment: If you seek yo prove it directly, that is a proof that constructs the result for all of them. If it is true for infinite $n$ then you require induction or contradiction. For contradiction it would be like assuming there exists an $n$ such that the premis isnt true or factors not congruent to 1 or 5. Then deducing a contradiction would show that they must at least be congruent to 1 or 5. Just to explain that if it helps. Induction would also work.

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is a prime factor of $n^2+4$ then $n^2\equiv-4\pmod p$, and $-4$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. Because $4$ is a square this is equivalent to $-1$ being a quadratic residue modulo $p$. It is well known that this is so if and only if $p\equiv1\pmod4$ (with the obvious exception $p=2$).

Therefore $p$ is congruent to either $1$ or $5$ modulo $8$, or $p=2$.

Comment: In case you have never seen it, the fact that $-1$ being a quadratic residue modulo $p$ implies $p\equiv1\pmod4$ is explained e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/735400/11619). Probably also earlier, that is one of the most often used tricks in elementary number theory.

Comment: correct to match  one part of the answer

Comment: @mmath: Sorry, what do you mean by *part of the answer*? I don't think there is anything missing :-)

Comment: ok, my apologise . everything is there

Comment: That's ok. I was just worried for a moment. May be I misread of something :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: the link you included states that $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ implies that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$... Shouldn't your first comment say that since $-1$ is quadratic residue, then $p - 3$ is not a multiple of $4$?

Comment: Correct, @Student. Sorry about that. I edited the comment (one of the diamond superpowers is the ability to edit old comments).